# zsh: command substitution does not inherit stdin from its parent

Tags: zsh, pipe, command-substitution, stdin, subshell

Consider the following command:

```
seq 5 | grep $(tail -n1) <(seq 9)
```

When running it in `zsh`<sup>1</sup>:

```
tail: error reading 'standard input': Input/output error
```

Now running the same in `bash`, it outputs:

```
5
```

OK. As explained in the comments, the command substitution `$(tail -n1)` inherits `stdin` from its parent. But why doesn't that happen with `zsh` ?
Is this a `zsh`-only thing or is it something that other shells do too ? Where is it documented ?

---

Now, if I run the same command via `zsh -c`:

```
zsh -c 'seq 5 | grep $(tail -n1) <(seq 9)'
```

instead of printing the same error message, it stops after `tail -n1` and waits for user input so if I type

```
19
2
4
```

then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, it prints

```
4
```

What's going on here ?

---

<sup>1: this is with `zsh` `5.3.1` on `archlinux`, if it matters.</sup>

Comment: it hangs on OSX El Capital with `zsh 5.3 (x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0)`

Comment: The [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/xcu_chap02.html) says that, during command substitution, the command is executed in a subshell and makes no mention of stdin being treated any differently. So a conforming shell would likely dup stdin and run each command substitution left-to-right, followed by running the primary command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll notice that in `bash`/`ksh`

```
echo foo | echo "$(cat)"
```

outputs `foo` but

```
<<< foo echo "$(cat)"
```

Doesn't.

In the first case, the `$(cat)` is expanded in the child process that will eventually execute `echo` after its stdin has been redirected from the pipe.

In the second case, the `$(cat)` is expanded before the redirection.

pipes and redirections are different things. pipes involve some *redirection* but also starting commands in parallel. That happens early, before the redirections inside each pipe component.

In `zsh`

```
$ sleep 1 | ps -jfH $(ps -fH >&2)
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
chazelas  2495  2494  0 20:59 pts/1    00:00:00 /bin/zsh
chazelas 31201  2495  0 21:20 pts/1    00:00:00   sleep 1
chazelas 31202  2495  0 21:20 pts/1    00:00:00   ps -fH
UID        PID  PPID  PGID   SID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
chazelas  2495  2494  2495  2495  0 20:59 pts/1    00:00:00 /bin/zsh
chazelas 31201  2495 31201  2495  0 21:20 pts/1    00:00:00   sleep 1
chazelas 31203  2495 31201  2495  0 21:20 pts/1    00:00:00   ps -jfH
```

You'll notice that this time the command substitution is expanded by the parent shell.

One thing to bear in mind is that in `zsh`, pipes are treated a bit more like redirections in particular when it comes to the `mult_ios` option (enabled by default).

When you do:

```
echo foo > file | tr o e
```

`foo` goes to both `file` and `tr`.

In:

```
uname | cat < /etc/issue
```

`cat` is fed both the output of `uname` and the content of `/etc/issue`. So in `zsh`, redirection from `<`/`>` and from pipe have to happen at the same stage. Preferably after the expansions.

In any case, you can always do:

```
echo foo | { echo "$(cat)"; }
```

in both `zsh` and `bash`/`ksh` like you can always do:

```
{ echo "$(cat)"; } <<< foo
```

in both `bash` and `zsh`.

---

As to the cause of the:

```
tail: error reading 'standard input': Input/output error
```

error. In interactive shells, since the command substitution is done in the parent, it's not done in the foreground process group of the terminal.

`tail` will be run in the process group of the parent shell. If that shell is the session leader, it will be an [orphaned process group](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_264), so when `tail` tries to read from the tty device, it  will fail with EIO.

If `zsh` was not the session leader. For instance, if you started `zsh` from another shell, then the process group would receive a SIGTTIN. The main shell process would ignore it, but `tail` would end up being suspended.